# uploading file to folder in node-express site using multer with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I have a node-express app that authenticates user data and upload files using multer, when i click on submit, the name, email, username and password fields are stored in the mongodb database. But the profileimage file is not stored in the uploads folder nor stored by monogdb. I tried using some help i found online but all worked with my app but did not store the picture in the folder nor did mongodb pass the profileimage field in the cli as expected by the model i used. Please What am I not getting right here, that's stopping the file from being uploaded and stored in the required folder and the name of the file being displayed in the mongodb cli?

Note: Other codes that worked fine with my app are commented in the below code sample but none stored the picture in the desired folder.

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');


var uploads = multer({dest: './uploads/'});

/*var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var originalname = file.originalname;
        var extension = originalname.split(".");
        filename = Date.now() + '.' + extension[extension.length-1];
        cb(null, filename);
    }
}); */

//Require a model page
var User = require('../models/user');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
    'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {
    'title': 'Log In'
  });
 });

//router.post('/register', multer({storage: storage, dest: './uploads/'}).single('profileimage'), function(req,res){
router.post('/register', uploads.single('profileimage'), function(req,res,next){
    //Get Form Value
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    //Check for Image field
    if(req.file){
        console.log('uploading File...');

        // File Info
        var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;

        var profileImageMime = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
        var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extension;
        var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
    } else {
        // Set a Default Image
        var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
    }

    /*if(req.file){
     console.log('uploading File...');

     // File Info
     originalname = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
     feildname = req.files.profileimage.fieldname;

     mimetype = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
     path = req.files.profileimage.path;
     encoding = req.files.profileimage.encoding;
     size = req.files.profileimage.size;
     } else {
     // Set a Default Image
     var original = 'noimage.png';
     } */

    //Form Validation
    req.checkBody('name', 'Name Field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email Field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username Field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password Field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    //Check for Errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            errors: errors,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password2: password2
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            profileImage: profileImageName

    });

        //Create User
        User.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        //Success Message
        req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may Log in');

        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var multer = require('multer');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//Handle File Uploads
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Handle Express Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

//Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


    module.exports = app;
```

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//This chooses the database to use for storing data a very important step
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');

var db = mongoose.connection;

//User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    profileimaage: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function (newUser, callback) {
    newUser.save(callback);
}
```

Comment: You need to use multer in users.js rather than using in app.js that is you need to define `var multer = require('multer');` and `var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });` in users.js and then try it. Please have a look [multer docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: @ArifKhan i'm using it there and even read through the documentation on github and npm but i did not get any further.

Answer (score 1):

create multerhelper.js file in your app nd add below code in it

```
const multer = require('multer');

// const fs = require('fs');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    let Id = req.body.id;
    let path = `tmp/daily_gasoline_report/${Id}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    cb(null, path);
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // console.log(file);

    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
}
})

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

let createUserImage = upload.single('images');


let multerHelper = {
createUserImage,

}

module.exports = multerHelper;
```

in your user.js file import this file

```
const multerhelper = require("../multerhelper.js");

router.post('/register',multerhelper  , function(req,res,next){
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are just loading the multer module not using anywhere.

Check the link for full uses :

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: I am using the multer module in users.js file.