# How to use multer function in controller instead of using in route

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I want to Use `multer` function in controller file But the problem is `req.body` got undefine when I use postman form-data body to upload images This is link to [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117357/12761193) that how I am using `multer` Function but I want use it in my controller

how I want to use it as you can see in below code

```
const multerHelper = require("../helpers/multer_helper");

Documents: async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    if (!req.body.id) {
        console.log(req.body)
        logger.warn(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
        return res.status(500).send(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS)
    }

    try {
        multerHelper.createUserImage
        let result = error.OK
        logger.info(result);
        return res.status(200).send(result)

    } catch (err) {
        logger.warn(err);
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(error.SERVER_ERROR)
    }
}
```

but it throws error like `req.body` undefine

req.body empty image
[image]

postman form-data image

[image]

Anyone know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `multer` functions and objects in only routes not in controller if you want to use it in controller you have to write storage and upload functions in controllers, here I have used `multer` error handling and I am uploading multiple images

```
Documents: async (req, res) => {

        if (!req.headers.room_id) {
            logger.warn(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
            return res.status(500).send(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS)
        }

        try {
            let storage = multer.diskStorage({
                destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                    let id = req.headers.room_id;
                    let path = `tmp/daily_gasoline_report/${id}`;
                    fsextra.mkdirsSync(path);
                    cb(null, path);
                },
                filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                    // console.log(file);
            
                    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
                    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
                    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
                }
            })
            var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('images', 100);
            upload(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.end("Error uploading file.");
                } else {
                    res.end("File has been uploaded");
                }
            });
            let result = error.OK
            logger.info(result);
            return res.status(200).send(result)

        } catch (err) {
            logger.warn(err);
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send(error.SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a parser?
How do you parse the data?
Your gonna need to use something that gives you this data something like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

this package helps you to parse the form data and the files data itself.

Comment: i am using multer for that like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117357/12761193 but now i want to use it in controller not in route

Comment: You need to understand what multer is going, its parsing the files data.
This express-fileupload is parsing the data and put it on the req.files
And then you will be able to use it on the endpoint